# Brownian Motion 3

Tags: brownian-motion

Let a stochastic process $X$ be defined by $X_t=\sqrt{t}\,Z$, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. Is $\{X_t,t\ge 0\}$ a standard Brownian Motion?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of standard Brownian motion? Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{X_t\}$ is not a standard Brownian motion because for $s<t$
$$X_t-X_s=(\sqrt t-\sqrt s)Z$$ which is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $(\sqrt t-\sqrt s)$. But not variance $t-s$.